# Better Touch Tool Similar

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, touchegg

I recently switch to ubuntu after some years of OSX.
One of the best tool I really miss is the awesome [better touch tool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/).
Do you know something similar?

At least I'd like to be able to switch chromes'tabs using 
a combination like (fn_key+touchpad scrolling), any advice?

Unfortunately touchegg doesn't work on my machine (dell ispiron 15)

Comment: Google can help. https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en